# ipad popOverController navigation Doubts

Tags: iphone

I am displaying a view controller as a popover on button click, and it seems to work fine.However selecting a tableview cell does not navigate to next page.
My first button click code is

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtnChapterselection:(id)sender
{
    //build our custom popover view
    BookSelectionview* popoverContent = [[BookSelectionview alloc]
                                         init];

    //resize the popover view shown
    //in the current view to the view's size
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover =
    CGSizeMake(500, 600);

    //create a popover controller
    self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                              initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

    //present the popover view non-modal with a
    //refrence to the button pressed within the current view
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:_btnChapterSelection.frame
                                            inView:self.view
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                          animated:YES];

    //release the popover content

    [popoverContent release];    
    [self resetReadViewToVerse:1];
}
```

in the didselectrowat index path clcik of BookSelectionview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ChapterSelectionView *detailViewController = [[ChapterSelectionView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChapterSelectionView" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.selectedIndex=indexPath.row;
    appDelegate.selectedBookIndex=indexPath.row;
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];
```

How do I make cell select navigate to Chapterselectionview?
please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is didSelectRowAtIndexPath called?

Comment: @Ankit Srivastava sorry,i didnt get u.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have UINavigationController into your pop-up, so it works normal. Change it to support navigation like this:

```
//build our custom popover view
BookSelectionview* popoverContent = [[BookSelectionview alloc]
                                         init];    
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverContent] autorelease];

//resize the popover view shown
//in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover =
CGSizeMake(500, 600);

//create a popover controller
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                              initWithContentViewController:navigationController];
```

Comment: haii sair, iput this code ,but no popovercomes when i click the button